# RDS Configuration is not available after installing ColdFusion 8 Eclipse extensions

Tags: eclipse, coldfusion

So I was following [this article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/debugger.html) and got to the **Setting up Eclipse for ColdFusion debugging** section, but step will not work for me because I don't see an "RDS Configuration option" as is shown in their figure 3 screen shot. I only see the other two options:

- Debug Mappings
- Debug Settings

What's gone wrong?

Comment: Look under Window > Preferences > Adobe > RDS Configuration

Comment: Are you using CFBuilder or CFEclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Window > show view > other > ColdFusion and enable RDS Dataview. You can get to the configuration settings from there by clicking on the page icon at the top of the palette.